# How to Resolve this error " 'password_reset' is not a registered namespace in rest api django"

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpBIL.png)

```
hi i am implementing password-reset feature on rest_API using `django_rest_passwordreset` library.but while testing end points its giving the following error:
```

NoReverseMatch at /api/accounts/password_reset/reset-password
  'password_reset' is not a registered namespace

```
please check the code below:


from django.urls import path,include
from account.api.views import SignupApiView
from account.api.views import UserCreationView
from account.api.views import ProfileView,EnableDisableUserView
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token



app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path("signup",SignupApiView.as_view(),name="signup"),
    path("create_user",UserCreationView().as_view(),name="create_user"),
    path("profile/<int:pk>",ProfileView.as_view(),name="profile"),
    path("disable_users/<slug:slug>",EnableDisableUserView.as_view()),
    path("disable_users/<int:pk>",EnableDisableUserView.as_view(),name="disable"),
    path("login",obtain_auth_token,name="login"),
    path('password_reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),#this is where i am getting the error
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try move your password reset urls to your main urls.py file

```
#in main urls.py
...
    path('api/password_reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
...
```

If you already have api/ urls included you can just make the url password_reset/ without api/ to avoid conflict